# helm: 'lookup' function always returns empty map

Tags: kubernetes-helm

The relevant docs: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function

My helm version:

```
$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.4.1", 
GitCommit:"c4e74854886b2efe3321e185578e6db9be0a6e29", 
GitTreeState:"dirty", GoVersion:"go1.15.4"}
```

Minimal example to reproduce:

1. Create a new helm chart and install it.

   ```
   $ helm create my-chart
   $ helm install my-chart ./my-chart
   ```
2. Create a simple ConfigMap.

   ```
   # my-chart/templates/configmap.yaml

   apiVersion: v1
   kind: ConfigMap
   metadata:
     name: my-configmap
   data:
     someKey: someValue
   ```

   Upgrade the existing chart so that the ConfigMap is applied.

   ```
   $ helm upgrade my-chart ./my-chart
   ```
3. Confirm that the ConfigMap exists.

   ```
   $ kubectl -n default get configmap my-configmap
   ```

   Which returns as expected:

   ```
   NAME           DATA   AGE
   my-configmap   1      12m
   ```
4. Try to use the `lookup` function to reference the existing ConfigMap.

   ```
   # my-chart/templates/configmap.yaml

   apiVersion: v1
   kind: ConfigMap
   metadata:
     name: my-configmap
   data:
     someKey: someValue
     someOtherKey: {{ (lookup "v1" "ConfigMap" "default" "my-configmap").data.someValue }}
   ```

   Then do a dry-run of the upgrade.

   ```
   $ helm upgrade my-chart ./my-chart --dry-run
   ```

   You will be met with a nil pointer error:

   ```
   Error: UPGRADE FAILED: template: my-chart/templates/configmap.yaml:9:54: executing "my-
   chart/templates/configmap.yaml" at <"my-configmap">: nil pointer evaluating interface 
   {}.someValue
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the `my-configmap` is staying in default name space?

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty Correct.

Comment: lookup usually returns `map` or `nil`,  can you check till `.data`  or may be without the `.data` as well , whats you are getting? just for debugging.

Comment: Without `.data`, the lookup returns `map[]`. But every key is `nil`, so `.data.someKey` results in a nil pointer exception.

Answer (score 5):

This is an expected behavior if you are using `--dry-run` flag.

From [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines#using-the-lookup-function)

> Keep in mind that Helm is not supposed to contact the Kubernetes API
> Server during a `helm template` or a `helm install|update|delete|rollback --dry-run`, so the lookup function will return an empty list (i.e. dict) in such a case.

Comment: Is this related to the deprecation of `kubectl apply --dry-run` in favor of either `kubectl apply --dry-run=client` or `kubectl apply --dry-run=server`? Until helm allows contacting the server during the dry-run, this `lookup` command is not useful to me because my CI/CD requires a passing dry run before a ... 'wet' run.

Comment: see the discussion here on when it will be available under `--dry-run`: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/8137

Comment: The `--dry-run=server` now is at least somewhat helpful in having working lookups.